# Determine, if JCDB connection for hibernate is still opened

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm facing a problem - in my application I use `hibernate` to access the database. It seems that everything is working allright, nevertheless when I don't use the application for some longer time ( ~day or more), it generates an error, when trying to access the database. I think, that it's because the connection has been closed and because I open it in via a class that is a `singleton`.
The code of this class:

```
package cz.cvut.fit.genepi.utils;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

// TODO: Auto-generated Javadoc
/*
 * class that handles connection with the database via hibernate 
 */
/**
 * The Class HibernateUtil.
 */
public class HibernateUtil {


    /** The Constant sessionFactory. */
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    /**
     * Builds the session factory.
     *
     * @return the session factory
     */
    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the session factory.
     *
     * @return the session factory
     */
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory==null)
            buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Shutdown.
     */
    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    } 
}
```

Is there any way, how to check, if connection is still opened, so I could be able to reopen it?
Is `getSessionFactory().isClosed()` what I'm looking for? So then I could write something like:

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory==null || getSessionFactory().isClosed())
            buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

I know I could simply try it, but the problem is, that it takes quite a long time to let this error to generate.

If you don't think, that this can be the source of the problem, here I inclose the stacktrace:
http://pastebin.com/6Yigjgt8

`hibernate.cfg.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>        

        <!-- property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:2080/genepi</property-->

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="./models/Patient.hbm.xml"></mapping>
        <mapping resource="./models/Contact.hbm.xml"></mapping>        
        <mapping resource="./models/Anamnesis.hbm.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Can you provide details of your connection pool configuration in hibernate.cfg.xml? Are you using C3P0? One way to solve this problem is to configure the pool to test connections on borrow.

Comment: I've updated my post. According to a fact, that I don't have any idea what shoud `C3P0` be, I expect, I'm not using it :)

Comment: This is worth a read: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool c3p0.idle_test_period should do the trick

Comment: Btw, the default hibernate connection pool is not recommended for production

Comment: Couldn't you just catch the exeption you are getting and reopen the connection if it occurs?

Comment: @André I don't think that to write try-catch block to everytime I need to work with the database is highly uneffective